# Варианты постановки знаков препинания в БСП

Tags: пунктуация, тире, бсп, двоеточие

Какие из представленных вариантов правильные?

1) "Вот увидишь - все наладится".
2) "Вот увидишь: все наладится".

Следующие предложения:
1) "Все наладится - вот увидишь".
2) "Все наладится: вот увидишь".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правила выбора заков препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения хорошо изложены [здесь](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185).

В соответствии с этими правилами выбираем следующие варианты:

**Вот увидишь: все наладится.** Вторая часть имеет значение дополнения, и перед ней можно вставить союз ЧТО

**Все наладится — вот увидишь**. Вторая часть предложения указывает следствие того, что описано в первой части и перед ней можно вставить союз ТАК ЧТО.

От себя добавлю, что на практике тире вытесняет двоеточие и часто используется вместо него.

Answer (score 0):

Да это ж что в лоб, что по лбу: абсолютно взаимозаменяемые знаки, вопрос вкуса и предпочтений.

Я люблю тире больше, чем двоеточие.

А во второй "группе" я вообще предпочла бы запятую.